# Problem with keys in graphicx: Package keyval Error: No value specified for

Tags: graphics, texlive-2020

I moved from texlive 2016 to texlive 2020. Something like:
`\includegraphics[quiet,scale=0.5]{OIP}`
which was working before, gives the error:
`Package keyval Error: No value specified for quiet`.

I am working with an iMac under catalina and using the latest version of the package macTeX.

**The code I use to test is**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document}
\includegraphics[quiet,scale=0.5]{OIP}
\end{document}
```

where "OIP" is any image you want in pdf. The full log I get is below:

```
** Log**
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.12.5)  5 DEC 2020 14:25
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test_quiet.tex
(./test_quiet.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen135
\Gin@req@width=\dimen136
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
(./test_quiet.aux)
\openout1 = `test_quiet.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count176
\scratchdimen=\dimen137
\scratchbox=\box46
\nofMPsegments=\count177
\nofMParguments=\count178
\everyMPshowfont=\toks16
\MPscratchCnt=\count179
\MPscratchDim=\dimen138
\MPnumerator=\count180
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count181
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks17
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))

./test_quiet.tex:14: Package keyval Error: No value specified for quiet.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 \includegraphics[quiet,scale=0.5]{OIP}
                                           
? q
OK, entering \batchmode...
<OIP.pdf, id=1, 597.23125pt x 845.1575pt>
File: OIP.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use OIP.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: OIP.pdf  used on input line 14.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 298.61488pt x 422.57771pt.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./OIP.p
df>] (./test_quiet.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1133 strings out of 480608
 16881 string characters out of 5903630
 250421 words of memory out of 5000000
 17073 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532636 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,5n,25p,187b,111s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on test_quiet.pdf (1 page, 29441 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what caused this change in behaviour, but the following provides a temporary fix:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\KV@Gin@quiet@default{\KV@Gin@quiet{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[quiet,scale=.5]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

Comment: one can also simply use `quiet=x` as key.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, but assuming that it was used a few times in the document, this change is just a single line and fixes every occurrence.

Comment: yes quite right, it was only a comment. The change happened between 2016 and 2017, just looking what was changed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer someone removed the empty `[]` in `\define@key{Gin}{quiet}[]{\let\Gin@log\@gobble}`.

Comment: it would have been odd if it was a simple removing, but the option was moved from pdftex.def and it seems it lost it in the transition.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it was one of the undocumented options added pdftex-only which we tried to normalise in the graphics-def collection moving , looks like we dropped the default can fix for next release

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I already created a PR for this.

Comment: @Skillmon thank you very much for your sugghestion. Indeed this "patch" solves my problem. But I noticed that I have the same problem with other options of includegraphics. If I understabd correctly yopur comment about [] missing, can I go on modifying my graphicx.sty and change all the \define@key{Gin}{"option"}{ into \define@key{Gin}{"option"}[]{  where "option" is bb, bbllx, bbly, bburx, bbury, viewport, trim, angle, width, height, totalheight, scale, type, ext, read, command, decodearray, quiet, page, pagebox

Comment: @praly no! most of those have no sensible default. Also do not modify graphics.sty patch the command as suggested in this answer.

Comment: @praly no, the other options need a value, they will break if you change them like this.

Comment: for sur bb gives the same "symptom" as quiet

Comment: yes, but this always was so, using only bb makes no sense at all, bb always need values so getting an error is the right thing.

Comment: @praly `quiet` has no required value, if you specify it logging is hidden. If you specify a bounding box then you _have_ to give all 4 coordinates what default would you give? If you use `[]` and default an empty string you will get multiple internal errors for missing numbers.

Comment: @all. Thank you all for your help. I fixed my problem by modifying my graphix.sty file changing   \define@key{Gin}{"option"}{     into     \define@key{Gin}{"option"}[]{   following the comment of   Skillmon.

Comment: you should not modify graphicx sty! If you want to make changes, then do it in a renamed version.

Comment: @praly you misread that comment. It was meant as the change that this particular key had in the past, and was directed at UlrikeFischer, because she and DavidCarlisle are among the people who have the rights to change things in the LaTeX core-packages. You shouldn't alter any of those packages locally, just put the quickfix-code in your document and/or wait for the real fix to be distributed. There is no need to make your local LaTeX installation error-prone by modifying existing packages.